# A backing store for training data in Numl.net and adding to it to improve accuracy

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm really interested in the [Numl.net library](http://numl.net/docs/webframe.html#GettingStarted.html) to scan incoming email and extract bits of data. As an example, let's imagine I want to extract a customer reference number from an email, which could be in the subject line or body content.

```
void Main()
{
    // get the descriptor that describes the features and label from the training objects
    var descriptor = Descriptor.Create<Email>();

    // create a decision tree generator and teach it about the Email descriptor
    var decisionTreeGenerator = new DecisionTreeGenerator(descriptor);

    // load the training data
    var repo = new EmailTrainingRepository(); // inject this
    var trainingData = repo.LoadTrainingData(); // returns List<Email>

    // create a model based on our training data using the decision tree generator
    var decisionTreeModel = decisionTreeGenerator.Generate(trainingData);

    // create an email that should find C4567890
    var example1 = new Email
    {
        Subject = "Regarding my order C4567890",
        Body = "I am very unhappy with your level of service. My order has still not arrived."
    };

    // create an email that should find C89779237
    var example2 = new Email
    {
        Subject = "I want to return my goods",
        Body = "My customer number is C89779237 and I want to return my order."
    };

    // create an email that should find C3239544-1
    var example3 = new Email
    {
        Subject = "Customer needs an electronic invoice",
        Body = "Please reissue the invoice as a PDF for customer C3239544-1."
    };

    var email1 = decisionTreeModel.Predict<Email>(example1);
    var email2 = decisionTreeModel.Predict<Email>(example2);
    var email3 = decisionTreeModel.Predict<Email>(example3);

    Console.WriteLine("The example1 was predicted as {0}", email1.CustomerNumber);


    if (ReadBool("Was this answer correct? Y/N"))
    {
        repo.Add(email1);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The example2 was predicted as {0}", email2.CustomerNumber);
    if (ReadBool("Was this answer correct? Y/N"))
    {
        repo.Add(email2);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The example3 was predicted as {0}", email3.CustomerNumber);
    if (ReadBool("Was this answer correct? Y/N"))
    {
        repo.Add(email3);
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Email
{
   // Subject
   [Feature]
   public string Subject { get; set; }

   // Body
   [Feature]
   public string Body { get; set; }

   [Label]
   public string CustomerNumber { get; set; } // This is the label or value that we wish to predict based on the supplied features
}

static bool ReadBool(string question)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(question);
        String r = (Console.ReadLine() ?? "").ToLower();
        if (r == "y")
            return true;
        if (r == "n")
            return false;
        Console.WriteLine("!!Please Select a Valid Option!!");
    }
}
```

There are a few things I haven't quite grasped though.

1. In a supervised network, do I need to re-build the decision tree every time I run the application, or can I store it off somehow and then reload it as and when required? I'm trying to save the processing time in order to rebuild that decision tree every time.
2. Also, can the network continually add to it's own training data as the data gets validated by a human? I.e. we have an initial training set, the network decides on an outcome and if a human says 'well done' the new example gets added to the training set in order to improve it. Also vice versa when the network gets it wrong. I assume I can just add to the training set once a human has validated that a prediction is correct? Does my `repo.Add(email)` seem like a logical way to do this?
3. If I do add to the training data, at what point does the training data become "more than required"?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a good problem to solve using machine learning (although I am interested in your findings).  My concerns would be that customer numbers change over time requiring you to regenerate the model each time. Binary classification algorithms such as Naïve Bayes, Decision Trees, Logistic Regression and SVMs require you to know ahead of time each class (i.e. Customer Ref No).

You could try using feature engineering and predicting whether a given word is or is not a customer reference number (i.e. 1 or 0).  To do this you simply engineer features like the below:

1. IsWordStartsWithC (bool)
2. WordLength
3. Count of Digits / Word Length
4. Count of Letters / Word Length

Then use Decision Tree or Logistic Regression classifier to predict if the word is a CRN or not. To extract the CRN out of the email, simply iterate over each word in an email and if Model.Predict(word) outputs a 1 you hopefully have captured the CRN for that email.

This method should not need to be retrained.

> 1. In a supervised network, do I need to re-build the decision tree every time I run the application, or can I store it off somehow and
>      then reload it as and when required? I'm trying to save the processing
>      time in order to rebuild that decision tree every time.

You can store the generated model using any stream object via the Model.Save() method.  All supervised models in numl currently implement this base class.  Apart from the Neural Network model they should save fine.

> 2. Also, can the network continually add to it's own training data as the data gets validated by a human? I.e. we have an initial training
>      set, the network decides on an outcome and if a human says 'well done'
>      the new example gets added to the training set in order to improve it.
>      Also vice versa when the network gets it wrong. I assume I can just
>      add to the training set once a human has validated that a prediction
>      is correct? Does my repo.Add(email) seem like a logical way to do
>      this?

This is a good reinforcement learning example.  At present numl doesn't implement this but hopefully it will in the near future :)

> 3. If I do add to the training data, at what point does the training data become "more than required"?

The best way to check this is through validation of the training and test set accuracy measures.  You can keep adding more training data while the accuracy of the test set goes up.  If you find that the accuracy goes down on the test set and continues to go up on the training set, it is now overfitting and it's safe to stop adding more data.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late, but I'm also learning the numl library, and I think I can shed some light on some of your questions.

> 1. In a supervised network, do I need to re-build the decision tree every time I run the application, or can I store it off somehow and
>      then reload it as and when required? I'm trying to save the processing
>      time in order to rebuild that decision tree every time.

There is currently a `IModel.Save` method that is supposed to be implemented in each class. However, as best I can tell it isn't yet implemented. There are, however, serialization tests that work for most models, including the DecisionTree, as shown in the DecisionTreeSerializationTests:

```
Serialize(model);
```

Which simply calls:

```
internal void Serialize(object o)
{
    var caller = new StackFrame(1, true).GetMethod().Name;
    string file = string.Format(_basePath, caller);
    if (File.Exists(file))  File.Delete(file);
    JsonHelpers.Save(file, o);
}
```

They have a bunch of custom created converters for using json serialization, and I think that this can be used until the model.Save is implemented. You basically just use the `numl.Utils.JsonHelpers` to serialize/deserialize the model to/from json (which you can persist however you want). Also, I think this is one thing that they are currently working on.

> 2. Also, can the network continually add to it's own training data as the data gets validated by a human? I.e. we have an initial training
>      set, the network decides on an outcome and if a human says 'well done'
>      the new example gets added to the training set in order to improve it.
>      Also vice versa when the network gets it wrong. I assume I can just
>      add to the training set once a human has validated that a prediction
>      is correct? Does my repo.Add(email) seem like a logical way to do
>      this?

You can always add data points to train your model at any point in time. However, I think you would have to retrain the model from scratch. There is [Online Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning) that trains as data points come in individually, but I don't think numl currently implements this. So, to do this you would probably run a daily/weekly job depending on your requirements to retrain the model with the expanded training data.

> 3. If I do add to the training data, at what point does the training data become "more than required"?

The general rule is "more data means better prediction." You can always look to see at your gains and decide for yourself if you aren't getting benefit out of increasing your training data sample size. That said, this is not a hard and fast rule (go figure). If you just google "machine learning more data better accuracy" you will find a ton of information on the subject, all of which I cull down to "more data means better prediction" and "see what works best for you". In your particular example of training against email text, it is my understanding that more data will only help you.

All of that being said, I'd also say a couple other things:

1. It sounds like if you're just trying to get customer/order numbers from emails, a good regex would do you better than analyzing with ML. At the very least, I would have regexs a part of the feature set of your training data, so maybe you could be training it to learn typos or input variations of your structure.
2. I'm not an expert on ML, nor on numl. I just happen to be learning numl as well. They have so far been very responsive to me on [gitter](https://gitter.im/sethjuarez/numl), which you and anyone else interested in the pretty awesome open-source, mature, MIT licensed library should definitely check out.